# Bash Scripting an Iterated Sequence of IPython Commands

Tags: bash

I am planning to run a series of commands in IPython, and I plan to do this in multiple iterations. Is there a way for me to streamline the process by making a shell script that:

1. Will activate the conda environment
2. Will activate IPython and execute a series of commands
3. Will exit IPython, move some files, etc.
4. Will return to Step 2 with a parameter in the commands changing in each iteration

Thank you!

I tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

source activate env name

for i in {0..1000}

do

ipython
import <package>
commands
commands
commands(arg, i)
commands
exit()

done
```

Comment: Why do they have to be run from an ipython interperter and not as a script?

Comment: Why not just use IPython instead of Bash? It can run shell commands with the `!` prefix.

Comment: Have you considered writing an IPython script (`.ipy` extension) and passing `$i` as an argument from Bash?